# Priests and leprosy

Tags: kohen-priest, health-safety-shmira, tzaraas-negaim

According to Leviticus 13, priests were to examine potential cases of leprosy.

Wouldn't the process of examination put the priest in danger of contracting leprosy himself?

Did the priests take any measures to protect themselves?

Comment: There are many species of can you explain how to contract leprosy of stones and clothes? for skin some leprosy come after a burn,. The priest need not to touch the skin.

Comment: [related](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69240/9215)

Answer (score 3):

Note that the meforshim (Rav Hirsh, Rav Sorotzkin, Ramban, Rambam, etc.) point out that tzara'at is not a natural disease and cannot be treated as a normal disease. That is, it is not similar to someone who gets (lo aleinu) something like TB as a punishment for a sin who must be treated for the physical disease **as well as** doing teshuvah for the sin.

Leprosy became interchangeable with the biblical leprosy due to two inaccurate translations: The Hebrew tzaraat was first translated into Greek as leprosy in the sixth century, and later, the word leprosy was translated into Arabic as lepra in the ninth century.

For example:

The kohen was not called during the week after a wedding or during chol hamoed. The person who appears to have tzaraas is not isolated until after the kohen sees him. Even if the kohen must be told by an expert what to say  he is not tamei until **after** the kohen makes the declaration. This shows that we are not concerned with the physical symptoms and it is not a medical quarantine.

The Mishna in [Moed Katan 1:5](http://mishnahyomit.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/issues/Vol8Iss47.pdf) discusses this.

> R’  Meir holds  that inspections  were  carried  out  on Chol Hamoed
>   but  that  the Kohanim were limited  to rendering a positive judgement
>   or remaining silent. The Rabbanan hold that the Kohanim were not
>   permitted to examine the nega at all  until  after  the  festival was
>   over.  The Halacha follows the Rabbanan,   but   both   opinions seek 
>   to   prevent   an individual from being banished from the community
>   during the festival.
>
> This  anomaly  can  be  explained  by  examining  the  true meaning
>   of Tzaraat. Tzaraat is often   mistranslated   as leprosy  (a 
>   contagious  bacterial  infection).  However  this translation  cannot 
>   be  correct. Rather, Tzaraat is  a  spiritual disease.  A  person only
>   becomes Tameh with Tzaraat once the Kohen declares   them   to   be
>   impure. They   are   not considered  ‘contagious’  unless  and  until 
>   this  declaration  is made.   This   contrasts   with   the
>   quarantine   placed   on someone with a physically contagious disease.
>
> Even  the greatest Talmid  Chacham is   not   qualified   to
>   diagnose Tzaraat if   they   are   not   a Kohen. [Rambam Hilchos Tumat Tzoraas 9:2](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1524516/jewish/Tumat-Tsaraat-Chapter-9.htm)

The gemara in Masechet Moed Koton daf 7a - 7b discusses the matter and points out that besides not being declared tamei during Chol hamoed, there are those who allow him to be with his wife once he has been confirmed to be a metzora (though not while confined for seven days.

Even if it were considered that Hashem is sending a physical disease as a punishment, we would have to treat the physical symptoms **as well as** the spiritual cause. this is not done, since if it were an infectious disease, the metzorah would have to be quarantined until the kohen declares that it is not *tzara'as* and it would be **more dangerous** to allow him to stay within the community during chol hamoed.

In 5760, there was an [article](http://ccs.infospace.com/ClickHandler.ashx?encp=ld%3d20160804%26app%3d1%26c%3dpchmeta4%26s%3dpchmeta4%26rc%3dpchmeta4%26dc%3d%26euip%3d71.179.216.48%26pvaid%3d2baa55baad654afdaadba296086b0024%26dt%3dDesktop%26fct.uid%3djp05i5bmm0%25253DA05E8B55-53E1-46FE-%26en%3dy2HsFdiwRo4XG8lJBjnZfEIb5hJQYreFhtNwVgkmv86Fivq2R5BG3f70oZbEEgfdEZn8H%252fCflYk%253d%26ru%3dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww.parsha.net%252fVayikra%252fMetzora60.doc%26ap%3d4%26coi%3d1494%26npp%3d4%26p%3d0%26pp%3d0%26mid%3d9%26ep%3d4%26du%3dwww.parsha.net%252fVayikra%252fMetzora60.doc%26pct%3dhttp%253a%252f%252fsct.pch.com%252fimages%252f__kl.gif%253fun%253dB02F3AC1-A606-4926-9349-6CAB7C6338A3%2526uid%253d6093b4b98935c828f40aa9612e3ef3ca%2526mobility%253ddesktop%2526searchID%253d6093b4b98935c828f40aa9612e3ef3ca1470323878471%26hash%3d13C3F9383A5044D83B4403B4AFF4EA25&cop=main-title) that discussed this> The [article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0190962282700106) is too long to give the details but the summary shows why the author decided that it does not match a disease known today. The article was published in the Jounal of the [American Academy of Dematology](http://www.jaad.org/article/S0190-9622(82)70010-6/abstract) in January 1982.

> From: Torah and Science[SMTP:torahandscience@avoda.jct.ac.il]
>   WHAT IS TZARAAT?
>   ABRAHAM R. FREILICH, MD
>   From the Division of Dermatology, Monteflore Hospital and Medical Center, Albert Einstein College of Medicine
>
> Leprosy has long been thought to be the disease referred to in the
>   Torah as  tzaraat.*(1) Upon close examination of the text of the
>   Torah, however, it  becomes apparent that the description of tzaraat
>   differs from our present  understanding of Hansen's disease and may
>   not be similar to any well‑known  dermatological disease.(2)  Here we
>   discuss the clinical features and  differential diagnosis of tzaraat,
>   based on the text and multiple commentaries  of the Torah. It is
>   important to note that tzaraat is discussed in a chapter of 
>   Leviticus dealing with ritual purity and impurity, a metaphysical
>   concept with  legal and practical ramifications.(3)  The strict
>   definitions of this state of  impurity, however, give insight into the
>   disease process.

Indeed, it is only when Bnai Yisrael were at a sufficiently high level that tzara'as occurred. Note also that the plague on clothing and houses are considered part of the same "disease". The meforshim point out that one could be warned by his house and clothing to be able to repent before it affects him. This shows it is not a medical condition.

Also note that a person is able to remove items from the house before the kohen makes the pronouncement and is not put in "quarantine" before the kohen announces that he is a metzorah. If it were being treated as a medical condition, then the objects in the house would be treated as if they were "infected".

It is considered that tzaraas does not occur nowadays. If it were one of the medical conditions suggested by the term leprosy, then a person with that medical condition would be treated in the same way as the Torah prescribes for *tzoraas*. That is, the disease would not have diappeared when Bnai Yisrael went down in the spiritual level.

As Rabbi Berel Wein says

> He implies that only where holiness exists – through the study and
>   knowledge of Torah – can the physical symptoms of impurity and
>   spiritual degradation be felt.

The [Encyclopedia Judaica](http://www.encyclopedia.com/article-1G2-2587512153/leprosy.html) says

> In fact, biblical descriptions of ẓaraʿat do not include the necrosis
>   associated with Hansen's disease. Thus far no skeletons of the
>   biblical period show any signs of Hansen's disease.

Rashi explains that we do not treat it as a (physical) disease sent by Hashem as a punishment, but as a totally spiritual one.

As Rashi says in [Tazria 13:46](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9914#showrashi=true&v=46)

> **He shall dwell isolated**: [meaning] that other unclean people [not stricken with tzara’ath] shall not abide with him. Our Sages said:
>   “Why is he different from other unclean people, that he must remain
>   isolated? Since, with his slander, he caused a separation [i.e., a
>   rift] between man and wife or between man and his fellow, he too,
>   shall be separated [from society].”- [Arachin 16b] [This rationale is
>   based on the premise that a person is stricken with tzara’ath as a
>   result of his talking לְשׁוֹן הָרַע, i.e., speaking derogatorily of
>   others, although he may be telling the truth.]

Comment: Can you add specific citations for your first sentence? Everything else here is either flat out wrong or doesn't actually address the question.

Comment: "The meforshim point out that one could be warned by his house and clothing to be able to repent before it affects him. THis shows it is not a medical condition." That is false. Medical conditions can be brought by Hashem as warnings.

Comment: "Also not that a person is able to remove items from the house before the kohen makes the pronouncement and is not put in 'quarantine' before the kohen announces that he is a metzorah. This also is not what would be rquired if it were a medical condition." This is false since Halakha is simply not prescribing a (full) treatment, and certainly not a modern one. It could still easily be a medial condition.

Comment: "As Rabbi Berel Wein says..." Completely irrelevant.

Comment: "The Encyclopedia Judaica says..." Only shows it might not be Hansen's disease. It could still be other things like psoriasis or vitiligo.

Comment: "The kohen was not called during the week after a wedding or during chol hamoed. The person who appears to have tzaraas is not isolated until after the kohen sees him. Even if the kohen must be told by an expert what to say (citation from gemarah?) he is not tamei until after the kohen makes the declaration. This shows that we are not concerned with the physical symptoms and it is not a medical quarantine." Correct(ish), but it does _not_ show that it's not a medical disease. Just that the Torah isn't treating it. (Alternatively the Torah is applying rules like Shomer Mitzva Lo Yeida Davar Ra)

Comment: "As Rash says in Tazria 13:46..." Completely irrelevant as God can use medical diseases as punishment.

Comment: So your source is a random author of a Mishna Yomi page repeating a common logical fallacy? Ok. Not so convincing.

Comment: "it is only when Bnai Yisrael were at a sufficiently high level that tzara'as occurred" "It is considered that tzaraas does not occur nowadays." Can you source this? Many think it's not true and tzara'as still occurs nowadays, just there is no Kohein to declare it Tamei. Indeed some hold the prohibition of cutting off skin lesions still applies in full force nowadays.

Comment: "since if it were an infectious disease, the metzorah would have to be quarantined until the kohen declares that it is not tzara'as." How do you know this isn't done as a health matter and not part of Hilchos Tzaraas?

Comment: "are considered part of the same 'disease'" The categorization here is pretty irrelevant; we have both viral and bacterial diseases which are similar to each other. "The meforshim point out that one could be warned by his house and clothing to be able to repent before it affects him. This shows it is not a medical condition." Why can't Hashem warn him using a medical condition on other objects?

Comment: It's amazing how many logical fallacies you can have in one post. Shows yet again that when someone grows up thinking something is true, it's hard to take a step back and reconsider.

Comment: @DoubleAA I added specific pointers to the gemara and to an article by an MD which gives the details and explains why the diseaes do not match.

Comment: All that article says is no single disease as we categorize them today matches all different kinds of tzaraat. That is of course irrelevant since our categories may not and probably do not match theirs. He does not claim to prove that tzaraat is not a medical disease.

Comment: @DoubleAA, so how about this, fleshed out, as an answer? "There's no reason to think _tzaraas_ is leprosy or any other disease that's communicated by proximity or touching. (Quarantining the _m'tzora_ is not evidence, as it's explained by commentaries as being for other reasons.)"

Comment: @msh210 Proving a negative is difficult, and it seems to me the burden of proof is on someone claiming that otherwise normal sounding skin lesions aren't a regular medical condition. Consider for example R Zelmel Volozhiner actions recorded here http://www.torahmusings.com/2014/04/contemporary-tzaraat/

Comment: @DoubleAA I didn't propose "it's proven not to be communicable": I proposed "there's no reason to think it's communicable". Note that common types of dermatitis/eczema aren't communicable, either. (I am not a medical professional.)

Comment: ... However, @DoubleAA, I see on the page you just linked to that he says that some sources that indicate that _tzaraas_ is communicable. So (according to those sources) never mind.